# NGRX Offline Cache with a PWA and Service Worker

Tags: angular, service-worker, ngrx, progressive-web-apps, ngrx-store

### This isn't a bug, but rather a question on how to approach my issue!

With the new PWA functionality for Angular it's quite simple to make your app work offline via a service worker.
My question is how to leverage NGRX to cache ones state, so that it is available offline.

I'm also concerned, that the client might modify the state when it's cached in the browser. (e.g. when using `ngrx-store-localstorage`)

Comment: Hey, Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: not a proper one... if you really need this I would suggest using the local browser storage (you can implement it yourself or use https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage).... but with this approach you have to be careful, because the user could potentially edit the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, a library such as `ngrx-store-localstorage` is the solution, there's no magic behind.

The concern about modifying the state isn't your problem. If someone wants to abuse the frontend of your app / website - he / she can do that. The main goal here is to assure that your backend doesn't accept malformed data (never trust data you receive from a user) and you don't store sensitive data in the frontend's store.

Anybody can open developers tools on this page and modify your question - up to them, because it is their local copy and it doesn't mean something is wrong with stackoverflow.

Comment: Over a year later, I definitely agree :)

Comment: Ah, crazy :) I've not seen the date :)